# Java, write string to notepad file

Tags: java, notepad

I just simply would like to add a string to a notepad file. Let's call the notepad file "Values.txt"
Say I have;

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

String myText = "Let's add this string to a notepad file";

// Code to add string to a notepad file

}
```

What would that code be?

Comment: Have you tried anything? Google?

Comment: WHat research have you done?

Comment: No such thing as a notepad file. There are file extension. The file extension `.txt` can be opened by notepad.

Comment: Just do some searching. I found thi for you anyway [Here is the code of java program to write text to a file:](http://www.roseindia.net/java/beginners/java-write-to-file.shtml)

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/ to get you started. Stack Overflow is for problems you can't solve yourself easily, and easiest way to demonstrate you tried is to show some code, tell or show what it does, *and* tell how that is different from what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at [Basic I/O tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/index.html). It is just manipulating a text file. All your needs should be covered there.